# WP8 - Login to Website and parse HTML from answer

Tags: c#, html, post, windows-phone-8, authentication

I want to login to this site: http://subcard.subway.co.uk/de_cardholder/JSP/login_reg.jsp
And i found out that I have to send a POST request to the server and I also know that I have to work with this POST request:

```
POST /de_cardholder/servlet/SPLoginServlet HTTP/1.1

Host: subcard.subway.co.uk

language=de&userID=ID&password=PASSWORD&transIdentType=1&programID=6
```

And after the login I want to parse the HTML data. But how can I implement the POST request on WP in C# and is it as easy as I think?

Comment: Are you asking about simple  web service POST?

Comment: I ask how it works under WP8 with C#

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Uri RequestUri = new Uri("subcard.subway.co.uk/de_cardholder/servlet/SPLoginServlet HTTP/1.1?language=de&userID=ID&password=PASSWORD&transIdentType=1&programID=6", UriKind.Absolute);
string PostData = "";
WebRequest webRequest;
webRequest = WebRequest.Create(RequestUri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

HttpWebResponse response;
string Response;
using (response = (HttpWebResponse)await webRequest.GetResponseAsync()) ;
using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
{
    Response = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
if(Response != null)
{
    //data should be available in Response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your Url here");

postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";// you can give the type of request content here
postRequest.Method = "POST";
```

if you have any data to be posted along with the request as part of content  and not as part of URL itself you can add this. example:- ( language=de&userID=ID&password=PASSWORD&transIdentType=1&programID=6)

```
using (var requestStream = await postRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
     byte[] postDataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your request data");
     await requestStream.WriteAsync(postDataArray, 0, postDataArray.Length);
}
```

if you do not have any data to be a send as content ignore the above code

```
WebResponse postResponse = await postRequest.GetResponseAsync();

if (postResponse != null)
{
    var postResponseStream = postResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var postStreamReader = new StreamReader(postResponseStream);

    string response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();// Result comes here
}
```

Comment: This sounds good, but for the GetRequestStreamAsync and the WriteAsnyc function there comes an error with "there is no function in httpwebrequest". I have all usings include, but I have no more ideas :(

Comment: I am getting the GetRequestStreamAsync method for the postRequest variable which is declared like in the code given(I am using System.Net.Http;'). It is available in .net frame work 4.5.